# Running 'make' Relilnks My Project Every Single Time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This question has been asked by people a couple of times before. However, my problem doesn't seem to match any of the other cases. I have custom targets in my Makefile and I am not really used to custom targets. Anyway, here is the Makefile. Thanks in advance :)

Makefile

```
# compiler
CXX=g++

# debug or release
Configuration=release

ProjectName=DiggerGuy

# directories
IncludeDirs=vendor/SFML/include include src
SourceDir=src
LibraryDirs=vendor/SFML/lib lib
BinaryDir=bin/$(Configuration)
IntermediateDir=bin-int/$(Configuration)

Binary=$(BinaryDir)/$(ProjectName)

# get the names of object files, placing them in intermediate directory
ObjectFiles=$(patsubst $(SourceDir)/%.cpp, $(IntermediateDir)/%.o, $(wildcard $(SourceDir)/**.cpp))

# links
Links=-lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lsfml-audio-s -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm

Defines=UNICODE _UNICODE SFML_STATIC

ifeq ($(Configuration), debug)
    CompileCommands=-g -c
    Defines += _DEBUG
else
    CompileCommands=-c
endif

# flags
CompileFlags=-Wall -O0 $(foreach D, $(Defines), -D$(D)) $(foreach D, $(IncludeDirs), -I$(D))
LinkFlags=$(foreach D, $(LibraryDirs), -L$(D))

$(IntermediateDir)/%.o:$(SourceDir)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CompileFlags) $(DebugSymbols) $(CompileCommands) $^ -o $@

all: $(Binary)
    @echo [Build Succeeded !]

$(Binary):$(ObjectFiles)
    $(CXX) $(LinkFlags) $^ -o $@ $(Links)

compile: $(ObjectFiles)

clean:
    rm -f $(Binary)
    rm -f $(IntermediateDir)/*.o

run:
    $(Binary)

.PHONY: all
```

This is what happens when I build my project and then build it again. It is a relink.

```
g++  -Lvendor/SFML/lib  -Llib bin-int/release/Main.o -o bin/release/DiggerGuy -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lsfml-audio-s -lgdi32 -lopengl3
2 -lwinmm
[Build Succeeded !]
```

Comment: What's a "custom target"?  Or to put it a different way, what *other* kind of target do you think is available?

Comment: `$(Binary)` is probably treated as an intermediate file and deleted after `make all`.  Either mark it as `.SECONDARY: ${Binary}` or remove the command in the `all:` target

Comment: @ensc, there is an explicit rule for `$(Binary)`, so it should not be treated as a secondary target.  And if it were, the problem description would more likely be along the lines of "make doesn't create my executable."

Comment: If you run `make` twice in succession, does the second run *only* relink the executable?  Or does it also recompile some of the sources?  The output from such a second run might be informative.  And the specific `make` commands you are issuing.

Comment: What filesystem type hosts the project directory?  It looks like you're on Windows, so is it NTFS?  exFAT? Maybe FAT32?

Comment: @JohnBollinger a pattern rule can never be a default target (how could it be, since it doesn't actually reflect any particular target to build?  If you run `make`, how does make know which target to create?)

Comment: There's an awful lot of guesswork here, most of it not really possible.  While there are some weird things in this makefile I don't see anything immediately wrong with it that would cause constant re-linking, so it must be something more subtle.  The right thing to do rather than making lots of guesses is to ask for more information.  Please show the result of running `make`, then immediately running `make` again (cut and paste, not screenshots, with formatting).  Then maybe we can see that the problem is.

Comment: @MadScientist, my thinking was that one of the targets matched to the pattern rule could, by virtue of the pattern rule being first, be the default target.  But of course that's circular -- `make` doesn't know that any targets it needs to build match the pattern rule until it knows at least one target it needs to build.  I deleted that comment, but I still think it's better form to put the rule for the default target before any pattern rules.

Comment: @John Bollinger, the project just links and none of the files are recompiled.

Comment: @John Bollinger I get relinking problem on running *make* or *make all* in any configuration set i.e. Configuration=debug or Configuration=release

Comment: I am running this in windows (NTFS)

Comment: I appended .exe to the binary target and suddenly it worked ! I wonder how that worked just by appending an exe format.